# iOS 14 UIColorPicker eyedropper tool not returning selected color

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, ios14, uicolorpickerviewcontroller

I am currently trying to implement the new iOS 14 UIColorPicker. Everything works great, except the `eye dropper` functionality of the UIColorPicker. After selecting the the eye dropper and sampling a color, the default behavior should be to re-open the UIColorPicker with your selected color as the active one. For some reason, this does not happen. Here is my implementation, its pretty standard, so I'm not sure why the eyedropper isnt behaving as expected.

I have these functions that are passed as the selectors for when I have some UI elements pressed

```
@objc func pickColorSky(sender: UIControl){
  presentColorPicker(tag: 1, sender: sender)
}

@objc func pickColorBackground(sender: UIControl){
  presentColorPicker(tag: 2, sender: sender)
}
  
@objc func pickColorGround(sender: UIControl){
  presentColorPicker(tag: 3, sender: sender)
}
```

Here is the function that presents the UIColorPickerView itself

```
@objc private func presentColorPicker(tag: Int, sender: UIControl){
    let vc = UIColorPickerViewController()
    vc.supportsAlpha = false
    vc.delegate = self
    vc.view.tag = tag
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sender.bounds
    self.present(vc, animated: true)
}
```

And the delegate methods to handle the interacting with the color picker

```
extension myViewController: UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate {
  
  func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
    guard let options = editor?.apiView?.getRenderingOptions() else { return }
      if viewController.view.tag == 1 {
        let newColor = getMobileApiColor(color: viewController.selectedColor)
        options.skyColor = newColor
        skyRow.color.backgroundColor = newColor.uiColor
      }
      else if viewController.view.tag == 2 {
        let newColor = getMobileApiColor(color: viewController.selectedColor)
        options.backgroundColor = newColor
        backgroundRow.color.backgroundColor = newColor.uiColor
      }
      else if viewController.view.tag == 3 {
        let newColor = getMobileApiColor(color: viewController.selectedColor)
        options.groundColor = newColor
        groundRow.color.backgroundColor = newColor.uiColor
      }
      editor?.modelView?.setNeedsDisplay()
  }
```

Comment: Sorry, Yogesh is right.  My ignorance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this method `colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor`

```
extension ViewController: UIColorPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    
    //  Called once you have finished picking the color.
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidFinish(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
        
    }
    
    //  Called on every color selection done in the picker.
    func colorPickerViewControllerDidSelectColor(_ viewController: UIColorPickerViewController) {
            self.view.backgroundColor = viewController.selectedColor
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right.

Comment: Hello @benjamin-morris, If this answer works for you then Please accept this answer  so it will helpful for others too.

Comment: @YogeshPatel this was not the solution to my issue, I will not mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You need to hold on to the picker object as a class member like this:

```
    private lazy var colorPicker = makeColorPicker()
private func makeColorPicker() -> UIColorPickerViewController {
        let vc = UIColorPickerViewController()
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.supportsAlpha = false
        return vc
}
```

Otherwise, it is removed from memory before you complete the eye-dropper step.